# Can't connect socket io on Android with server nodejs

Tags: android, ios, node.js, sockets

I follow code at page: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/
and download, run successfully project https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat.
And I want to connect socket io with my node server

Code at: server nodejs version of socket io "version": "1.3.5",

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io'),
http = require('http'),
port = process.env.PORT || 8080,
ip = process.env.IP || '192.168.0.105', //My IP address. I try to "127.0.0.1" but it the same => don't run
server = http.createServer().listen(port, ip, function() {
console.log("IP = " , ip);
console.log("start socket successfully");
});

io = socketIO.listen(server);
//io.set('match origin protocol', true);
io.set('origins', ':');

var run = function(socket){

socket.on("message", function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});

socket.on("user-join", function(value) {
    console.log(value + "user-join");
    socket.broadcast.emit("new-users", value);

});
}

io.sockets.on('connection', run);
```

Code at Android:

```
package com.example.phamhuu.chatnodejs;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Socket mSocket;
{
try {

        IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.port = 8080;
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.105:8080");
        //mSocket = IO.socket("http://chat.socket.io");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e("abc", "index=" + e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSocket.connect();
    Log.e("result socket connect", String.valueOf(mSocket.connected()));
    mSocket.emit("message", "Send message to server.");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I make sure add 'android.permission.INTERNET'
I try it on real device (My PC and my device the same wifi )but socket can't connect to server at address: 192.168.0.105 port: 8080
Can you help me?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure that this port is open or not used at that moment you try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question, but if you want to create a chat with Node.JS which works for also android clients, you can take a look at the alternative: [JXM](http://jxm.io/) (on [github](https://github.com/jxcore/jxm)) - messaging backend for [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) (open sourced fork of Node.JS).

The problem you describe here probably will not be relevant any more.

There are practically ready samples to be used as they are (server part; clients: browsers, android, node).

I've wrote my few cents on this subject here: [Simple Node.js chat program NOT using socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586092/simple-node-js-chat-program-not-using-socket-io/29594114#29594114)